# Getting a function pointer to a dynamic library in C (C89)

Tags: c, visual-studio, shared-libraries, function-pointers, c89

I have a function pointer to a dynamic library,

```
#include <GL/gl.h> /* or something */

void (*vertex)(float, float) = &glVertex2f;
```

On GCCi686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 it's always worked, but fails on Visual Studio 2010 with,

```
error 'vertex': address of dllimport 'glVertex2f' is not static
```

I have it configured for C89; I believe that's the only C available. The idea is that I want to invoke the function pointer as an `extern` in other files that do not include the library headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <GL/gl.h>

void (*vertex)(float, float);
```

and explicitly,

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vertex = &glVertex2f;
    ...
}
```

fixes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Windows DLLs do not work like BSD/Linux shared libraries :(

I believe you need the `GetProcAddress` function.

This link was just pulled from Google: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This looks promising, but I am not including Windows.h if I can possibly avoid it.